# How To Install Node Js In Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

i'm trying to install nodejs in Ubuntu 18.10 but it returns some error.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs : Depends: python-minimal but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Above is the message i get while install node Js by cammand: sudo apt-get install nodejs.

Comment: Did you, at least, try to google "Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages." ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html):

Install node version manager:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.0/install.sh | bash
```

Activate nvm:

```
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Use nvm to install the version of node you want:

```
nvm install 4.4.5
```

Test that Node.js is installed:

```
node -e "console.log('Running Node.js ' + process.version)"
```

Comment: Sure. I will do that!

Answer (score 1):

The [recommended](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) way to install `node` under Ubuntu appears to be to use the archives provided by [NodeSource](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md).

Their instructions are to run these shell commands to, presumably, set up a PPM and install a current version of `node` from that source.

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install python 2.7 using following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python2.7
```

then install nodejs

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using Ubuntu

curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

## Using Debian, as root

curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs

Answer (score 0):

To install always latest #nodejs on Ubuntu/Windows/Macbook.

Step 1- Download Node js package from node js official website https://nodejs.org/

Step 2 - Extract it from command `tar xf` & rename folder as **node**.
Step 3 - Open Terminal go to node path on your computer. `cd <<Your Path>>`
Step 4 - excute command `sudo cp -r node/{bin,include,lib,share} /usr/`

You see your node successfully installed. To check version use `node -v`.

For more details you can check reference from [How To Install Node js in your computer](https://youtu.be/79p7SZuENeE)

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal:

```bash
$ sudo apt install snap
```

Node install:

```bash
$ sudo snap install node --classic
```

Install node package manager:

```bash
$ sudo snap install npm
```

Check node version:

```bash
$ node --version
```

Check npm version:

```bash
$ npm --version
```